# add images inside rectangle phaser io

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to add those apple to not go out of the shape below. here is the code for that in phaser io:

```
rectangle = new Phaser.Rectangle(game.world.centerX - 300, game.world.centerY - 300, 600, 200);
bmd = game.add.bitmapData(game.width, game.height);
bmd.rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height, '#fff')
bmd.addToWorld()

var gm = this;
var w = rectangle.width,
h = rectangle.height, 
x = rectangle.x, 
y = rectangle.y;
height = y - h,
mid = height/3;
img = {'width':0};
var group = game.add.group();
for(var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    var imgWidth = rectangle.x + img.width  * a;
    img = this.game.add.image(imgWidth, rectangle.y + mid, 'apple');
    //img.anchor.setTo(0.5);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Should this have been an edit to your existing question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50997873/11912

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding images to Phaser.Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997873/adding-images-to-phaser-rectangle)